# Write a General Filter Type Class?

Tags: scala

Given the following, I believe, type class:

```
  trait Element[A, B] {
    val input: A
    val filteredValue: Option[B]
  }
```

I then defined `filterFn` to filter on input `queryFilterValues`, and then filter the curried `List[A]`, returning a `List[A]`, i.e. what's been filtered:

```
def filterFn[A, B](queryFilterValues: List[B])
                  (implicit ev: A => Element[A, B]): List[A] => List[A] = 
    elements => {
     queryFilterValues match {
        case _ :: _ => elements.flatMap { e =>
          ev(e).filteredValue match {
            case Some(v) => if(queryFilterValues.contains(v) ) List(e.input) else Nil
            case None    => List.empty
          }
        }
        case Nil    => elements.map(_.input)
      }
    }
```

Then, I created a `Person`, along with an `Person => Element[Person, String]` instance:

```
case class Person(name: Option[String])
object Person {
  implicit def personToElement(p: Person) = new Element[Person, String] {
    val input         = p
    val filteredValue = p.name
  }
}
```

Finally, I tried to use it:

```
// Filter on these names
val nameFilters = List( "jane", "joe", "will" )

val joe = Person( Some("joe") )

// Expect to get a `List( joe )` back since `joe#name` exists in the list.
scala> filterFn( nameFilters )( List[Person](joe) )
```

But I get the following compile-time error:

```
<console>:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Person]
 required: ? => Element[?,String]
       filterFn( nameFilters )( List[Person](joe) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of filterFn is

```
def filterFn[A, B](queryFilterValues: List[B])
              (implicit ev: A => Element[A, B])
```

When you call it with

```
filterFn( nameFilters )( List[Person](joe) )
```

You're passing in `List[Person](joe)` as the 2nd argument. But the signature you have defined expects a function from `A` to `Element[A, B]`

This is why you see

```
 found   : List[Person]
 required: ? => Element[?,String]
```